# How to require a file that is bundles separately and wrapped as an external?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I need to have a file that is required be packaged into the build directory, and then wrapped to allow referencing that file from the file that was requiring it. This probably doesn't make any sense, so let me show that the pipeline would look like.

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
   ...
};
```

**index.js**

```
import config from './config.js';

console.log({config});
```

When Webpack bundles this, the output structure would be something like:

```
dist
  index.html
  main.bundle.js
  config.js
```

**config.js**

```
global.__WEBPACK_REQUIRE_CONFIG_JS__ = (() => {
  const module = {};
  module.exports = {
    ...
  };
  return module.exports;
})();
```

**index.js**

```
const config = global.__WEBPACK_REQUIRE_CONFIG_JS__;

console.log({config});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

My reason for this is our build pipeline needs to modify `config.js` prior to releasing. I have no control over this. I can think of some interesting hacks to make it work, but I'd like to do something succinct.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, you need to use the SplitChunksPlugin. If someone wants to write up an answer around that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `SplitChunksPlugin`. It's part of webpack. Your webpack configuration would look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
       splitChunks: {
         cacheGroups: {
           vendor: {
             test: path.resolve(ROOT_DIRECTORY,'src/config.js'),
             name: 'config',
             filename: 'config.js',
             chunks: 'initial',
             enforce: true,
            }
         }
       }
    },
}
```

This will create a file in the build folder called `config.js` that contains the contents of your config file. If you use `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, it will automatically be included before your main module is included.

The `enforce` option tells webpack to always generate the chunk, regardless of its size. The `chunks` option tells webpack which chunk to put it with. In this case `initial` means to load it at page load.